# Chosen.js show selected count

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen.js as the DropDownList extension in my project and I was wondering whether it is possible to change the display of the multiple chosen.js.

My problem is that I have a tightly packed form in which I have a multiselect dropdown.In this case, I require both search and the multiple functionality. Now chosen shows the selected items like so:

[image: from choosen's examples]

I cannot afford that, therefore I need a way to alter what is displayed to something like this:

[image: modified chosen]

I'd rather not opt for using a different plug-in in this case to keep code and UI integrity, however if no simple solution is available so be it.

Comment: All the times I need to make that kind of things, I modify the original chosen plugin, and it works, but I need to solve lot of problems after that. My opinion, it's better if you construct your own plugin. You will develop less than modifying the original plugin.

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread?

Comment: I guess I kind of opted towards what @Marcos Pérez Gude said. So we do use chosen for anything that is one value select and we use this thing for what I've asked above https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget